I am trying to make a snake game using the Python Turtle graphics, but it ends as soon as it starts
I'm not too sure what is wrong, as I tried to cross check with the code given in the course that I am taking. The issue comes up when I try to add the code for the collision with its own tail. If I try without it, it works fine. However, when I do add the code, it runs but shows the game over as soon as it starts.
This is the code for the main.py.
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import time
from snake import Snake
from food import Food
from scoreboard import ScoreBoard

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.bgcolor("black")
screen.title("Snake Game")


# starting 

game_over = Turtle

snake = Snake()
food = Food()
scoreboard = ScoreBoard()


# movement

UP = 90
DOWN = 270
RIGHT = 0
LEFT = 180

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.turn(UP), 'Up')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.turn(LEFT), 'Left')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.turn(RIGHT), 'Right')
screen.onkey(lambda: snake.turn(DOWN), 'Down')


game_on = True

def food_collision():
    if snake.snake_head.distance(food) < 20: # distance checkes snaake head distance from food 
        food.change_pos()
        snake.extend()
        scoreboard.increase_score()

def tail_collision():
    for segment in snake.segments[1:]:

        if snake.snake_head.distance(segment) < 10:
            game_on = False
            scoreboard.game_over()


while game_on:
    
    screen.update()
    time.sleep(0.1)
    food_collision()
    
    
    # collision with wall
    if snake.snake_head.xcor() > 280 or snake.snake_head.xcor() < -280 or snake.snake_head.ycor() > 280 or snake.snake_head.ycor() < -280:
        game_on = False

        scoreboard.game_over()

    #collision with 
    tail_collision() 
    
    snake.move()



screen.exitonclick()

here is the code for the snake.py
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import time

screen = Screen()

START_POSITION = [(0, 0), (-20, 0), (-40, 0)]

MOVE_DIST = 20

class Snake:

    def __init__(self):

        self.segments = []
        self.create_snake()
        self.snake_head = self.segments[0]
        


    def create_snake(self):

        

        for snake_body in START_POSITION:
            self.add_segment(1)

    def add_segment(self, position):

        a = 0
        snake_body = Turtle("square")
        snake_body.color("white")
        screen.tracer(0)
        snake_body.penup()
        snake_body.setpos(x=a, y=0)
        a -= 20
        self.segments.append(snake_body)

    def extend(self):
        self.add_segment(self.segments[-1].position())

    def move(self):
           
        for seg_num in range(len(self.segments) - 1, 0, -1): # start, stop, step
            # getting cord of previous segmets
            new_x = self.segments[seg_num - 1].xcor()
            new_y = self.segments[seg_num - 1].ycor()

            # last segment moves to cord of next segment
            self.segments[seg_num].goto(new_x, new_y)

        self.snake_head.forward(MOVE_DIST)
        


    def turn(self, direction):

        if direction - 180 != self.snake_head.heading() and direction + 180 != self.snake_head.heading():
            self.snake_head.setheading(direction)
        else:
            pass

this is the code for the food.py
from turtle import Turtle
import random

class Food(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.shape("circle")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(0.6)
        self.color("blue")
        self.speed("fastest")


    def change_pos(self):

        rand_x = random.randint(-280, 280)
        rand_y = random.randint(-280, 280)

        self.goto(rand_x, rand_y)
        

this is the code for the scoreboard.py
from turtle import Turtle

class ScoreBoard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.score = -1

        self.color("white")
        self.penup()
        self.goto(0, 280)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.update_scoreboard()
        
    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.write(f"Score: {self.score}", align="center", font=("Arial", 15, "normal"))


    def increase_score(self):
        self.score += 1      
        self.clear()      
        self.update_scoreboard()
        
    
    def game_over(self):
        self.goto(0, 0) 
        self.write("Game Over", align="center", font=("Arial", 25, "normal"))
        


ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'food'. We're also missing ScoreBoard. Please share a [mcve]. Note that while loops are poor design in turtle. Prefer ontimer. screen.tracer(0) should be called one time globally rather than in a snake method.

the food module is in the other file called food.py in which i made a class called Food. this only changes its position when the snake goes 20 px near it and the score increases by 1.  and i added the screen tracer in the snake method so that it refreshes everytime there is a new method. the scoreboard is also in another file the onlything it has is a game over function which only shows the game over title and in the main.py this is used to end the game it alkso increases the score.

i have edited it, please review it and mention any mistakes and recommendations

Thanks, voted to reopen. There are a number of issues, but the main one is snake_body.setpos(x=a, y=0) where a=0, the same location as the head. Try x=-20 instead. Also, your update loop is out of order. Move the snake, then check collisions, then update the screen, and finally sleep. Add tracer(0) as the first thing, right after making the global screen in main. Avoid subclassing Turtle. Here's a gist, which has a good deal of additional cleanup. I'll add an answer if this gets reopened (please ping me).

thank you very much it works perfectly now

Updated gist link (old one deleted--I used the wrong account).

The issue is likely due to the scope of the game_on within  tail_collision(). When you set game_on = False inside the function, it creates a new, local variable names game_on instead of modifying the global one. But despite the name it's different variable. To fix your code, declare game_on as a global variable inside the tail_collision()
def tail_collision():
  global game_on  # Declare as global to modify
 ... 


i tried the solution but it shows the same issue
